# Sapper : prevent client javascript to run on server

Tags: preload, sapper

I'm beginning with Sapper ^^' I'm trying to use a derived store to find and preload some images as following :

```
export const backgroundDatas = derived([id, backgroundsRegistry], ([$id, $backgroundsRegistry]) => {
    let datas = $backgroundsRegistry ? $backgroundsRegistry[$id] : null;

    if(datas && !datas.preload)
    {
        datas.preload = new Image();
        datas.preload.src = datas.url;
    }

    return datas;
});
```

But it appeared I couldn't use that derived store in component `<script>` first execution (`Image is not defined` error) because `new Image()` doesn't make sense on the server, seems logical x),  so I though I could rely on reactiv statements inside the component in order to use that store. Here is what I did :

```
$: if (currentBackgroundDatas != $backgroundDatas)
  {
    // make some animation to change background
  }
```

The problem is that the check `currentBackgroundDatas != $backgroundDatas` seems to be evaluated on the server, and therefore is throwing `Image is not defined` error.

Is there any safe way to use that derived store ?
In a more generic and architectural way, how do you prevent client javascript to be called on server ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `onMount`

```
import { onMount } from 'svelte';

onMount(() => {

  // will run on the client

});
```

Comment: Thx ! ok for using lifecycle callback in order to prevent client javascript to beexecuted on server. But is that the only way ? Because in the specific case I showed, the error is triggered by the  `$ : if`, and, according to some test on the REPL, there is no way to use it inside onMount.

Comment: You could do 

`let mounted = false;  

onMount(() => { mounted = true });

$: if (mounted && currentBackgroundDatas != $backgroundDatas) { }`